# OnSelectedIndexChanged event occurs on one page and doesn't on another one

Tags: asp.net, postback, procedure, autopostback, selectedindexchanged

I guess this question is a difficult one. I have two pages with just the same functionality. First one is for People. The second one was created as a copy and then modified a little for Products.

I have **DropDownLists** on both pages, both DDLs have **OnSelectedIndexChanged** events and **AutoPostBack options enabled**. Both pages have code-behind procedure **RefreshPage** which reloads the page with **id** parameter. This **id** parameter is the actual selected value in dropdownlist.

So, by design:

1) I change DDL's selected item, it does AutoPostBack and fires OnSelectedIndexChanged event.

2) This event runs **RefreshPage** procedure, which adds currently selected value of the DDL to QueryString and reloads the page with it.

3) Then this ID is taken from QueryString and set to DDL. See the code.

**RefreshPage** successfully works on the **People.aspx** page. But similar procedure on the **Products.aspx** never runs at all. I added breakpoints into the same place of both procedures - the line with **Page.Response.Redirect** method. On the first page it stops and shows correct value of the parameter **paramID**, but the second page never reaches breakpoint. **OnSelectedIndexChanged** event is simply skipped.

Both pages have **EnableViewState disabled**. I don't use javascript or AJAX. I don't use **PreRender** methods.

Here is my code.

People.aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddJGroup" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RefreshPage" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="DropDown" Font-Bold="True"/>
```

People.aspx.cs:

```
protected void RefreshPage(object s, EventArgs e)
{
    paramID = ddJGroup.SelectedValue;
    Page.Response.Redirect("People.aspx?id=" + paramID);
}
```

Products.aspx:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddCType" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RefreshPage" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="class_DropDown" Font-Bold="True"/>
```

In both pages I take the **id** parameter from QueryString and set the selected value of DropDownLists using it in the Page_Load procedure. See below.

Products.aspx.cs:

```
...
if ((Request.QueryString["id"] != null) && (Request.QueryString["id"] != ""))
    paramID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
...
ddCType.DataSource = sqlReader;
ddCType.DataValueField = "c_type_id";
ddCType.DataTextField = "type_name";
ddCType.DataBind();
ddCType.SelectedIndex = ddCType.Items.IndexOf(ddCType.Items.FindByValue(Convert.ToString(paramID)));
```

This code works fine. But on the **Products.aspx** the parameter **paramID** never changes. It should change in the **RefreshPage** procedure, but the procedure never runs and never changes **QueryString["id"]** parameter. I mean, this page is never reloaded from **RefreshPage**, it just always does simple PostBack.

In the RefreshPage procedure:

```
protected void RefreshPage(object o, EventArgs e)
{
    paramID = ddCType.SelectedValue;
    Page.Response.Redirect("Products.aspx?id=" + paramID);
}
```

If this procedure ran, the page would reload with new **id** parameter and dropdownlist would get this new index.

Comment: Not enough information to say why the event is not fired. Please upload both Products.aspx and Products.aspx.cs.

Comment: Did all events fires accordingly in Products.aspx after DropDownList is selected? In other words, Page_Load should fire first; then DropDownList and so on. Set a break point at all events including Page_Load and debug it.

Comment: Also make sure `AutoEventWireup="true"`, `CodeBehind="Products.aspx.cs"` and `Inherits="PROJECTNAMESPACE.Products"` in `Products.aspx`

Comment: Could you enable the view state (by deleting `EnableViewState="false"`) and test it again?

Comment: I have updated the topic with more details.

Answer (score 0):

I would Say 70-90% of the **DropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged** event not getting fired because of error in some Data Bindings to Controls in your page ,

check to see the Binding in your page and check if your not binding it each time the page loads check the:

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
mydropdownlist.DataSource=yourDataSource;
mydropdownlist.DataBind();


}
```

so it won't Bind each time a postback event occur and thus the IndexChanged won't get fired

regards